# How to get sidebars.js to work

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-plugins

I was just trying to use **[THIS](http://plugins.adchsm.me/slidebars/usage.php)** plugin on a small project of mine. , I have gone through the **[USAGE](http://plugins.adchsm.me/slidebars/usage.php)** section multiple times and also checked the example files once downloaded from git(none of the example files actually work ! ) and so i have the following HTML::

```
<div class="sb-slidebar sb-left sb-style-push">
  <!-- Your left Slidebar content. -->
  <p>Just a line of text to demonstrate the push effect.</p>
</div>

<div id="sb-site">
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Sint, tenetur fuga voluptas ducimus quis nulla velit esse suscipit, quidem tempore. Quisquam quod nisi, magni labore dolorem corporis, cum modi nobis!
</div>
```

and the following jQuery init code:

```
$.slidebars();
```

and ofcourse the sidebar css and js files linked. but somehow the plugin does't work , i am assuming that the hamburger is created internally in the JS of sidebars , not sure how it all work but i am not able to create a sidebar meenu , can somebody point me to what am i doing wrong ?

**[FIDDLE HERE](https://jsfiddle.net/n0o0ztgf/1/)**.

I just want to get this sidebar menu working.

Comment: Tried with different versions. All I get is `Uncaught TypeError: $.slidebars is not a function`. It's clearly broken or maybe it doesn't work because jsFiddle won't let you set `<meta>` tags. (It's the only thing in setup steps that can't be completed in fiddle). Take it to the plugin author. Don't forget to come here and post the solution after you find it, there might be more like you, although in your shoes I'd have given up on it after the first 10 minutes. Perhaps faster.

Answer (score 1):

*The following is using version 0.10.3.*

Using the [control classes](http://plugins.adchsm.me/slidebars/usage.php#control-classes) described in the usage section I was unable to get the sidebar to open at all.

What did work for me was using the [API](http://plugins.adchsm.me/slidebars/usage.php#api) methods.

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
   var mySlidebars = new $.slidebars();

   $('.toggle').on('click', function() {
     mySlidebars.slidebars.toggle('left');
   });
 });
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/n0o0ztgf/2/)